# Div not fading first time with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have a div fade in `onClick`, and fade out again when something in the div is clicked. But, for some reason, the first time I try to show the div it just appears, but the first time it hides and every other show/hide, it fades properly. Here's what I have for the fade functions:

```
<script>
    function show_eform() {
        document.getElementById('eform').style.visibility = 'visible';
        $('#eform').fadeIn('fast');
    }
    function hide_eform() {
        $('#eform').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            document.getElementById('eform').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        });
    }
</script>
```

And for the div's CSS:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 50;
visibility: hidden;
```

To trigger:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_eform()">
```

Comment: You don't need to mix jQuery and vanilla DOM like that.

Comment: @MattBall is it particularly bad practice?

Comment: Can you post the code that calls these functions?

Comment: can you add the code that triggers the functions.

Comment: I agree with MattBall, pick jQuery or Vanilla.  No need to mix the two together unless there is a vanilla function that is not specifically supported by jquery (i.e. setTimeOut).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function show_eform() {
    $('#eform').fadeIn('fast');
}

function hide_eform() {
    $('#eform').fadeOut('fast');
}
```

And use `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;` like:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 50;
display: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that might help you understand the fadein/fadeout and toggle functions:
http://jsfiddle.net/g9AU9/1/

For fadeIn/fadeOut/toggle type functions you don't have to set any visibility states, those functions take care of it for you.

HTML

```
<div id="eform" style="display:none;">This is an eform</div>
<div class="toggle_form">Toggle Eform</div>
<div class="hide_form">Hide Eform</div>
```

CSS

```
#eform { background:orange; padding:10px; }
.toggle_form { background:yellow; padding:10px; cursor:pointer; }
.hide_form { background:lime; padding:10px; cursor:pointer; }
```

JS

```
show_eform();

function show_eform(){
    $('#eform').fadeIn('fast');
}

function hide_eform() {
    $('#eform').fadeOut('fast');
    $(".toggle_form").hide();
}

$(".toggle_form").click(function() {
    $('#eform').slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".hide_form").click(function() {
    hide_eform();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('eform').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

with this line you directly display the div so just remove the line and just fadeIn and fadeout functions you also don t need to set visibility in the end of the animations.